# Tailing a file from where I left off before?

Tags: linux, unix, tail

Suppose I have a file. I `tail` its last 10 lines and got some data. And the next time I come to `tail`, its length increases by 4. So I need to `tail` only that many lines to get data. Is there a simple command line for this?
Like a mix of `tail`, `wc`, and `grep`?

Comment: Why is this tagged C++? Are you looking for a C++ solution or shell commands?

Comment: I'll remove my comment - since after removing your explanation it won't be clear what this is about. I'll also edit out the c++ tag... I reckon you'd get more viewers with relevant knowledge then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save the size of the file when you close tail, you can do `tail -c +[previous size]`. This starts at a specific byte offset of the file instead of a number of lines from the end. This may be subject to a race condition if the size changes between when you close the first tail process and when you measure the size.

Why are you closing and reopening the tail command, instead of just using the `-f` option and continuing reading?

Comment: @PrasanthMadhavan : I agree with @Random832, in that you're design doesn't seem right (maybe it is). Do you know about the unix concepts of fifos, pipes and/or reading on stdin? Maybe your program can be modified to read directly from the file instead of calling execlp and creating new processes. Good luck!